# recursive query on two fields

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I 'm trying to write `CONNECT BY PRIOR` on two fields. Any got any idea?

Eventually I want something like following. Unfortunately it seems not working

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
CONNECT BY PRIOR emp.type = emp.parenttype AND emp.ID = emp.ParentID
```

Create table script:

```
CREATE TABLE emp ( 
    ConnectionPkID NVARCHAR2(16) Not Null, 
    EmpType NVARCHAR2(2) Not Null, 
    EmpID NVARCHAR2(20) Not Null, 
    ParentID NVARCHAR2(20) Not Null, 
    ParentType NVARCHAR2(2) Not Null, );
```

Comment: Can you provide us a CREATE TABLE script and a sample of data?

Comment: What error message are you getting? Or how is it "not working"?

Comment: CREATE TABLE emp
(
ConnectionPkID NVARCHAR2(16) Not Null,
EmpType NVARCHAR2(2) Not Null,
EmpID NVARCHAR2(20) Not Null,
ParentID NVARCHAR2(20) Not Null,
ParentType NVARCHAR2(2) Not Null,
);

When I select LEVEL all the levels are 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this test data:

```
SQL> select * from t23
  2  /

        ID TYP  PARENT_ID PAR NAME
---------- --- ---------- --- --------------------
         1 P                  Fox in Socks
         2 P                  The Lorax
         1 C            1 P   Mr Knox
         2 C            1 P   Daisy-Headed Maisie
         3 C            2 P   Mr KnoHortonx

SQL>
```

this version of your query works:

```
 SQL> select level, t23.*
from t23
connect by prior t23.id = t23.parent_id
and prior t23.type = t23.parent_type 
start with t23.parent_id is null and t23.parent_type is null
/
  2    3    4    5    6  
     LEVEL         ID TYP  PARENT_ID PAR NAME
---------- ---------- --- ---------- --- --------------------
         1          1 P                  Fox in Socks
         2          1 C            1 P   Mr Knox
         2          2 C            1 P   Daisy-Headed Maisie
         1          2 P                  The Lorax
         2          3 C            2 P   Mr KnoHortonx

SQL>
```

The important bit is to tag each operand in the CONNECT BY clause with PRIOR.

Comment: That was it. I did n't put two PRIOR. I read [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm) this documentation on Oracle and I thought they meant I could use only one.

Comment: That link clearly states "you can have multiple PRIOR conditions" and gives pertinent examples.

Comment: I know I could have multiple PRIOR. The sentence "then only one condition requires the PRIOR operator" has confused me. Thanks for your help APC

Answer (score 2):

`PRIOR` is a part of condition, not of `CONNECT BY` clause. You need to qualify each parent field with it. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
CONNECT BY PRIOR emp.type = emp.parenttype AND PRIOR emp.ID = emp.ParentID
START WITH emp.ID = ??? AND emp.type = ???
```